# cant deploy CDK EKS Blueprints Karpenter addon

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I am trying to use the Karpenter CDK EKS Blueprint addon, but when deploying it keep getting this error:

`Received response status [FAILED] from custom resource. Message returned: Error: b'error: resource mapping not found for name: "default" namespace: "" from "/tmp/manifest.yaml": no matches f or kind "Provisioner" in version "karpenter.sh/v1alpha5"\nensure CRDs are installed first\n'`

I used the same code as shown on the official cdk blueprint page but it is not working :/
https://aws-quickstart.github.io/cdk-eks-blueprints/addons/karpenter/

Here is my sourcecode:

```
export class EksStack {

    constructor(app: cdk.App, id: string, props: EksStackProps) {
        const addOns: Array<blueprints.ClusterAddOn> = [
            new blueprints.AwsLoadBalancerControllerAddOn(),
            new blueprints.CertManagerAddOn,
            new blueprints.SecretsStoreAddOn(),
            new blueprints.ArgoCDAddOn({

                //adminPasswordSecretName: props.argoCdConfig.adminPasswordSecretName,
                bootstrapRepo: {
                    repoUrl: props.argoCdConfig.repoUrl,
                    path: props.argoCdConfig.path,
                    targetRevision: props.argoCdConfig.targetRevision, //main
                    credentialsSecretName: props.argoCdConfig.gitSecretName,
                    credentialsType: props.argoCdConfig.gitCredentialsType //SSH,
                },
                bootstrapValues: {
                    spec: {
                        kmsKey: props.kmsKey.keyArn,
                        syncPolicy: {
                            automated: {
                                selfHeal: true,
                                prune: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }),
            new blueprints.CalicoOperatorAddOn,
            new blueprints.MetricsServerAddOn,
            new blueprints.ContainerInsightsAddOn,
            new blueprints.VpcCniAddOn,
            new blueprints.CoreDnsAddOn,
            new blueprints.KubeProxyAddOn(), //https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/managing-kube-proxy.html
            new blueprints.KarpenterAddOn({
                version: "v0.29.2",
                requirements: [
                    //{ key: 'node.kubernetes.io/instance-type', op: 'In', vals: ['m5.2xlarge'] },
                    //{ key: 'topology.kubernetes.io/zone', op: 'NotIn', vals: ['us-west-2c'] },
                    //{ key: 'kubernetes.io/arch', op: 'In', vals: ['amd64', 'arm64'] },
                    { key: 'karpenter.sh/capacity-type', op: 'In', vals: ['on-demand'] },
                    { key: 'kubernetes.io/os', op: 'In', vals: ['linux'] },
                ],
                subnetTags: {
                    "aws-cdk:subnet-name": props.eksSubnetGroupName,
                },
                securityGroupTags: { "Name": props.nodeSecurityGroupName },
                taints: [{
                    key: "workload",
                    value: "test",
                    effect: "NoSchedule",
                }],
                amiFamily: "AL2",
                consolidation: { enabled: true },
                ttlSecondsUntilExpired: 2592000, // 30 Days
                interruptionHandling: true,
                limits: {
                    resources: {
                        cpu: 1000,
                        memory: "100Gi"
                    }
                },

            })
        ];

        const clusterProvider = new blueprints.GenericClusterProvider({
            version: KubernetesVersion.V1_27,
            managedNodeGroups: [{
                id: `eks-nodegroup`,
                instanceTypes: [new aws_ec2.InstanceType('t3.small')],
                minSize: 1,
                maxSize: 1
            }],
        })

        blueprints.EksBlueprint.builder()
            .clusterProvider(clusterProvider)
            .account(props.env.account)
            .region(props.env.region)
            .addOns(...addOns)
            .resourceProvider(blueprints.GlobalResources.Vpc, new blueprints.DirectVpcProvider(props.vpc))
            .teams(
                new blueprints.PlatformTeam({
                    userRoleArn: `arn:aws:iam::${props.env?.account}:role/${props.teams.tempPlatformTeam.roleName}`,
                    name: props.teams.tempPlatformTeam.teamName,

                }),
                new blueprints.PlatformTeam({
                    userRoleArn: `arn:aws:iam::${props.env?.account}:role/${props.teams.platformTeam.roleName}`,
                    name: props.teams.platformTeam.teamName,
                }),
            )
            .enableGitOps(blueprints.GitOpsMode.APP_OF_APPS)
            .build(app, id).addDependency(props.dependency);
    }
}
```

I am expecting CDK to automatically install all required dependencies like CRDS and Charts to be able to deploy Karpenter properly